# Getting the cURL stream in PHP

Tags: php, curl, stream

1. If I run `curl_exec` with no options, the fetched page gets output on php's standard output (the html page being served back).
2. If I run it with the `RETURNTRANSFER` option set, I can get the whole page in a variable.

How can I get a stream, that I can then manually parse?

In case 1, I cannot access the data to parse it and in case 2, I need to wait until it is fully downloaded before starting to parse it. I would like something similar to `fopen()` and `fread()` where `fread($curl_handle, 1000)` would return as soon as the first 1000 bytes have been read, and the second call would be return after 2000 bytes have been read, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested by [this answer I gave some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342583/php-manipulate-a-string-that-that-is-30-mil-chars-long/1342760#1342760) : I explained and gave an example of using stream wrappers with curl, to be able to work with the data while it's being fetched -- which seems to be what you want to do.

It's probably not an exact answer to your question, but it could be what you needed to start implementing a solution ;-)

Comment: Wow thanks, that looks great, I'm just a little disappointed that there is no built-in way of doing it, but I'll try with your class.

Comment: Tou're welcome :-) ;; well, I suppose what you are trying to do is not that common ^^ ;; but it's kind of "built-in", afterall : streams are a great functionnality of PHP, even if not used quite enough...