# Stream response from CURL request without waiting for it to finish

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script on my server that is making a request to another server for an image.

The script is accessed just like a regular image source like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/imagecontroller.php?id=1234" />
```

Browser -> Script -> External Server

The script is doing a CURL request to the external server.

**Is it possible to "stream" the CURL response directly back to the client (browser) as it is received on the server?**

Assume my script is on a slow shared hosting server and the external server is blazing fast (a CDN). Is there a way to serve the response directly back to the client without my script being a bottleneck? It would be great if my server didn't have to wait for the entire image to be loaded into memory before beginning the response to the client.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Pass the `-N`/`--no-buffer` flag to `curl`. It does the following:

> Disables the buffering of the output stream. In normal work
>   situations, curl will use a standard buffered output stream that will
>   have the effect that it will output the data in chunks, not
>   necessarily exactly when the data arrives. Using this option will
>   disable that buffering.
>
> Note that this is the negated option name documented. You can thus use
>   --buffer to enforce the buffering.

Comment: this worked! this should have been the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION flag:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $callback);
```

Where `$ch` is the Curl handler, and `$callback` is the callback function name.
This command will stream response data from remote site. The callback function can look something like:

```
$result = '';
$callback = function ($ch, $str) {
    global $result;
    $result .= $str;//$str has the chunks of data streamed back. 
    //here you can mess with the stream data either with $result or $str
    return strlen($str);//don't touch this
};
```

If not interrupted at the end `$result` will contain all the response from remote site.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Pascal Martin's answer to an unrelated question, in which he discusses using CURLOPT_FILE for streaming curl responses. His explanation for handling " [Manipulate a string that is 30 million characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342583/php-manipulate-a-string-that-that-is-30-mil-chars-long/1342760#1342760) " should work in your case.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not with curl, you could use fsocket to do streaming.

Comment: you can, just need to diable CURL's default buffering, with the
`--no-buffer`
option, to force CURL not to use buffering (which does by default)