# How to use low level socket functions socket_write/socket_read to handle ssl requests in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

I need to send request and receive response over a ssl https connection. One requirements is to only use low level socket function (**NOT STREAM**), such as socket_write/socket_read, socket_send/socket_recv, listed on http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Comment: you could use some code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277982/php-stream-download-website-content-until-string-found)

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried the code on http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php, but it was for a http request NOT a ssl request

Comment: @Stefan fsockopen is NOT what I want. I need to use socket_create

Comment: We won't do your homework btw

Comment: @Stefan Oh this is really not my homework. I can use socket functions to handle normal http request. But for ssl connections, the low level socket functions seem not that easy. I tried to use Ev library for async processing, and it can only monitor FD/Sockets so that I must use the low level socket functions

Comment: Didn't know about `stream_socket_enable_crypto()`. See my answer below. Good question! :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` on the connected socket. To enable ssl on the socket there are 4 possible options that depend on environment and version. you can try each of them unless one will work. Image this example:

```
function enableCrypto($socket)
{
    $modes = array(
        STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT,
        STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT,
        STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT,
        STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv2_CLIENT
   );

   foreach ($modes as $mode) {
        if (stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, $mode)) {
            return;
        }
   }

   throw new Exception('failed to enable crypto');
}
```

Btw, the example is taken from the HTTP_Request2 package from the PEAR repositories. The function above is nearly the same as HTTP_Request2_SocketWrapper::enableCrypto(). You may find further information by have a look at the source code of HTTP_Request2.

Comment: I tried to pass stream_socket_enable_crypto to $socket created by socket_create, but none of the modes can be set to $socket. This function might be still for stream

Comment: Yes, sorry I tried it too. :( . Is using streams an option? (Would suggest) Should I prepare an example?

Comment: I can use streams if the Ev library supports. But EvIo does not seem to monitor stream. I am still trying to find a solution. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Interesting stuff the `Ev` extension. Will dig into it. Can I understand your question like 'How can I perform a https request using the Ev extension?' ?

Comment: btw why don't you just use stream_select(), or socket_select() ?