# How to get an HTTP response as a stream in PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl

My application's backend in PHP sends HTTP requests to other servers and receives large responses from them.

At the moment I'm using `curl_setopt($curlResource, CURLOPT_FILE, $fileResource);` to avoid storing the response in memory so I don't have to increase memory limits for the script.

What I want to achieve is for my script to receive the HTTP response from other server and to process it in real-time, discarding pieces of data already processed.

Is it even possible without something fancy like a socket connection to ports 80 or 443 to receive data without the help of CURL?

Comment: tried curl_getinfo ()

Comment: [You might be interested in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1342760/227884)

Comment: @Thrustmaster, thanks a lot, looks like **exactly** what I need.
Create a proper answer, if you want, so I could mark it as the right one.

Comment: @sp-niemand Thanks, but I dont deserve credit for that answer; Martin does. You can upvote his post, and close/delete your question here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief answer: use your own custom stream object as a `CURLOPT_FILE`.

You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1342760/227884 .