# How can I get the HTML of a curl request within a specified time

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have a script using curl to get the html of a webpage.  Sometime it gets information perfectly, while other times it seems to hang.  I put in a timeout provision -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

So now the script no longer hangs, but when it does timeout, it doesn't return any of the html.  Is there a way for curl to get all html it's received before the timeout?  Or, is there some other way to achieve the idea - "get all the html you can within a specified period of time from a URL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CURLOPT_FILE`

Example:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("/path/to/save/file", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

echo file_get_contents("/path/to/save/file");
?>
```

Comment: it's always nice to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a stream wrapper, you can even parse the data on-the-fly. Have a look at this:
[Manipulate a string that is 30 million characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342583/manipulate-a-string-that-is-30-million-characters-long/1342760#1342760)

Comment: This is great but a lot more complicated than I was hoping for.  It seems like it would solve my issue.  So if no other solution can be found, I will do this.  Thanks!