# Read Massive CSV File From S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku, amazon-s3

I have big csv files on my S3.
I want to import their data without download(copying) them to my tmp folder on heroku.
Plus i dont want to load whole file in memory.
Can you guys suggest me how can i do that. Some thing like getting data chunk by chunk or anything like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this would only be possible if Amazon had an api where you could ask for a specific set of lines from a file, which AFAIK doesn't exist.  I think your best option is to copy the file onto your server and then read it in one line at a time (various CSV libraries let you do this).  This way you can avoid having it all in memory.  I don't think you can avoid having it in memory AND avoid saving the file locally.

Comment: Both `curl` and `wget` can write the stream to `STDOUT`, which you could presumably read directly from a pipe.  Have you tried that approach?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot aha, great idea.  This post has some methods to do this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342583/manipulate-a-string-that-is-30-million-characters-long/1342760#1342760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I thought of a way to do this, which is insanely inefficent and pretty stupid.  But, if you are **determined** to not save the file on your server then here's a way.

You add code to your app which accepts some data (eg a line, or lots of lines worth) in some form, and then creates the records accordingly.  Deploy this.

Then, on your LOCAL machine, save the file.  Write a script which reads the file in (again, a line at a time is best to avoid memory issues), converts it into the format needed for action you wrote, and then send it as a GET or POST request to your production site.  It will need to make lots of requests as it churns through the file.

Like I say, this is really stupid and a little insane:  you really should just save the file on your server.

Comment: yes after reading your comments i am saving the file on my system. was just curious if i can read the file directly. thankyou for all the help.

Comment: You can, i think, using @Michael - sqlbot's streaming CURL, but it's really not worth the effort compared to just saving the file.